# Add to first element active class

Tags: twig

I want to add active class to my first slide. I try to do like this

```
  {% for slide in slides %}
     <div class="item {% if loop.index == 1 %}active{% endif %}
     ....
  {% endfor %}
```

But in result i add active class to all of my slides. Pleasem help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

*Can you try with `loop.first` ?*

**[Here is the doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)**

```
 {% for slide in slides %}
     <div class="item {% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}
     ....
  {% endfor %}
```